# Should I generate UUID's in application or in the database?

Tags: python, postgresql, performance, sqlalchemy, uuid

PostgreSQL will be used in production and it has native support for UUID's.

But how should I handle generation of them?

Currently I use following:

```
uuid = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid4().hex)
```

With this they are generated by the application.

Would it be a performance improvement if the database generates them and how could I implement that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The great advantage of uuids is that they can be generated on the client.

This means that, for instance, you could create an invoice, with all the invoice lines, without having to hit the database to get an invoice id first.

As such, you should not generate it in the database, unless you are doing so, using a stored procedure that will insert data in more than a table.

Comment: This is a really old issue but in the modern cloud era I have a real life example of why you want to do this on the app. I just ran into a bug with Azure responding with an error to my mobile app, apparently after a serverless function had already completed, which triggered a retry call to the API, which generated a duplicate entry because the API was responsible for generating the UUID. If the app had done this it would've been blocked  by the database as the ID needs to be unique. A real edge case that revealed this issue to me.